Avoiding Extra slice() in Bubble Sort While Keeping Functional Immutability
I'm working with TypeScript that follows functional programming principles, meaning I want to keep immutability and avoid mutating any of the input arrays.
I'm using bubble sort, and I have an issue where I need to return a new sorted array without modifying the original one.
However, my current implementation seems to be adding unnecessary overhead by adding a .slice() at the end to create a new array.
export default function bubbleSort<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, compare: (a: T, b: T) => number): ReadonlyArray<T> {
  // Helper function to swap elements in an array
  const swap = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, i: number, j: number): ReadonlyArray<T> => {
    const newArr = [...arr]
    ;[newArr[i], newArr[j]] = [newArr[j], newArr[i]]
    return newArr
  }

  // Function to perform one full pass of bubble sort, bubbling the largest element to the end
  const bubblePass = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, n: number): [ReadonlyArray<T>, boolean] => {
    // Slice the array to ignore already sorted elements
    return arr.slice(1, n).reduce(
      ([accArray, swapped], _, i) => {
        if (compare(accArray[i], accArray[i + 1]) > 0) {
          return [swap(accArray, i, i + 1), true] // Swap if necessary and mark as swapped
        }
        return [accArray, swapped]
      },
      [arr, false] as [ReadonlyArray<T>, boolean],
    )
  }

  // Recursive function to apply the bubble sort until no more swaps are needed
  const sort = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, n: number): ReadonlyArray<T> => {
    if (n <= 1) return arr // Base case: if the array length is 1 or less, return the array
    const [newArr, swapped] = bubblePass(arr, n)
    return swapped ? sort(newArr, n - 1) : newArr // Recur with the size reduced by 1 if swapped, else return sorted array
  }

  return sort([...array], array.length)
}

Then, the errors happen:
const arr = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]
const sorted = bubbleSort(arr, (a, b) => a - b)
sorted.push(123) // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly number[]'.

It works with slice method at the end
export default function bubbleSort<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, compare: (a: T, b: T) => number): T[]  {
  // Helper function to swap elements in an array
  const swap = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, i: number, j: number): ReadonlyArray<T> => {
    const newArr = [...arr]
    ;[newArr[i], newArr[j]] = [newArr[j], newArr[i]]
    return newArr
  }

  // Function to perform one full pass of bubble sort, bubbling the largest element to the end
  const bubblePass = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, n: number): [ReadonlyArray<T>, boolean] => {
    // Slice the array to ignore already sorted elements
    return arr.slice(1, n).reduce(
      ([accArray, swapped], _, i) => {
        if (compare(accArray[i], accArray[i + 1]) > 0) {
          return [swap(accArray, i, i + 1), true] // Swap if necessary and mark as swapped
        }
        return [accArray, swapped]
      },
      [arr, false] as [ReadonlyArray<T>, boolean],
    )
  }

  // Recursive function to apply the bubble sort until no more swaps are needed
  const sort = (arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, n: number): ReadonlyArray<T> => {
    if (n <= 1) return arr // Base case: if the array length is 1 or less, return the array
    const [newArr, swapped] = bubblePass(arr, n)
    return swapped ? sort(newArr, n - 1) : newArr // Recur with the size reduced by 1 if swapped, else return sorted array
  }

  return sort([...array], array.length).slice()
}

The Issue: The .slice() at the end solves the immutability issue, but it seems to be a waste of performance, especially since the array has already been copied during the sorting process.

That little .slice() at the end is nothing compared to the overhead of const newArr = [...arr] in every swap() call. But if you're implementing a bubble sort, you probably don't care a lot about efficiency anyway?

Bubble sort with an array copy at every step is O(n^3) time. If you need to return a sorted array without mutating the original one, just make one copy at the start of the function and then do an ordinary imperative sort. There is no benefit of translating the bubble sort algorithm into the functional style. Even the correctness benefits of avoiding mutation don't apply here. Bubble sort is one of the most well-known, studied algorithms and it can be written in 3 lines of code, which makes it very easy to check that an implementation is correct.

For the types to work correctly, we have to get rid of ReadonlyArray. Instead of .slice, you can use the i < n - 1 check in .reduce.
Here is my sample code:
export default function bubbleSort<T>(array: ReadonlyArray<T>, compare: (a: T, b: T) => number): T[] {
  // Helper function to swap elements in an array
  const swap = (arr: T[], i: number, j: number): T[] => {
    const newArr = [...arr];
    [newArr[i], newArr[j]] = [newArr[j], newArr[i]];
    return newArr
  }

  // Function to perform one full pass of bubble sort, bubbling the largest element to the end
  const bubblePass = (arr: T[], n: number): [T[], boolean] => {
    // Slice the array to ignore already sorted elements
    return arr.reduce(
      ([accArray, swapped], _, i) => {
        if (i < n - 1 && compare(accArray[i], accArray[i + 1]) > 0) {
          return [swap(accArray, i, i + 1), true] // Swap if necessary and mark as swapped
        }
        return [accArray, swapped]
      },
      [arr, false] as [T[], boolean],
    )
  }

  // Recursive function to apply the bubble sort until no more swaps are needed
  const sort = (arr: T[], n: number): T[] => {
    if (n <= 1) return arr // Base case: if the array length is 1 or less, return the array
    const [newArr, swapped] = bubblePass(arr, n)
    return swapped ? sort(newArr, n - 1) : newArr // Recur with the size reduced by 1 if swapped, else return sorted array
  }

  return sort([...array], array.length)
}


On the one hand you could replace return [accArray, swapped] with return [[...accArray], swapped], on the other hand it doesn't seem important to me. We are returning return sort([...array], array.length) at the end of all code anyway, which means we are still returning a new array.

Ah, sorry, I missed that the sort function here is not the one exposed publicly.
